# successful call with null body in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit for login Api. I got successful response with null body. 
I tried to debug the app and search about it but nothing useful  but I didn't figure out what is go wrong

**Here is the response I should receive**

> {
>       "headers": {},
>       "original": {
>           "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8yMDkuOTcuMTM1LjIzOVwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTUzMTY3ODE1OSwiZXhwIjoxNTMxNjgxNzU5LCJuYmYiOjE1MzE2NzgxNTksImp0aSI6ImZHMXIyN1QwZVY0TldxMVAiLCJzdWIiOjQ0MSwicHJ2IjoiZTVjYjM4YmY4ZDIzZGQ2ZWE4ZWFiODIwZDk1NTVlNmI3NGU2NzU0ZSJ9.GeB2gqSKNf2ebq-z-FkYg328aOUqYmkkBlL8rIBM9p0",
>           "token_type": "bearer",
>           "expires_in": 3600
>       },
>       "exception": null }

**here is my class model**

```
public class login_Resp {
@SerializedName("headers")
@Expose
private String headers;
@SerializedName("access_token")
@Expose
private String accessToken;
@SerializedName("token_type")
@Expose
private String tokenType;
@SerializedName("expires_in")
@Expose
private int expiresIn;
@SerializedName("exception")
@Expose
private Object exception;

public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

public String getTokenType() {
    return tokenType;
}

public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
    this.tokenType = tokenType;
}

public int getExpiresIn() {
    return expiresIn;
}

public void setExpiresIn(int expiresIn) {
    this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
}


public String getHeaders() {
    return headers;
}

public void setHeaders(String headers) {
    this.headers = headers;
}
public Object getException() {
    return exception;
}

public void setException(Object exception) {
    this.exception = exception;
}
```

**main Acitivity**

```
 loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mobile  = myidText.getText().toString();
                String password=myPassword.getText().toString();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile) && 
                   !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    login(mobile, password);
            }

            }
        });
    }
       private static String token;
       private void login(String mobile ,String password);
       Login login = new Login("store",mobile,password);
       Api_Interface service = 
       Api_Client.getClient().create(Api_Interface.class);
       // Call<String> call = service.storeLogin(login);
       Call<login_Resp> call = service.storeLogin(login);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<login_Resp>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<login_Resp> call, Response<login_Resp> response) {
               if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                   Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body());
              token = response.body().getAccessToken();
           }
           else{
                   Log.i(TAG, "login is  not correct." );}
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<login_Resp> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
           }
       });
```

Comment: you should have original as separate class, it represents another object

Comment: What response code are you getting?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I add original class but still return null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    private Object headers;

    private Object exception;

    private Original original;

    public Original getOriginal ()
    {
        return original;
    }

    public void setOriginal (Original original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public Object getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(Object headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    public Object getException() {
        return exception;
    }

    public void setException(Object exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
    }
}


public class Original
{
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    private String accessToken;

    @SerializedName("token_type")
    private String tokenType;

    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    private int expiresIn;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public int getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    public void setExpiresIn(int expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }
}
```